# .NET disable keyboard shortcuts - from a SPECIFIC input device

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard

I would like to disable, with run-time configurability, various keyboard combinations (Alt+Tab, Ctrl+F, etc.) from  the primary keyboard on Windows.

I'd still like to be able to emulate these key combinations through software-based means, such as the approach shown at https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/.

Every example I've found disables the key combinations completely, but I only want to disable the key combinations if they come from the main keyboard.

Any thoughts on the feasibility of this?  My current prototype is a .NET service that is written in C#.

Comment: Do you need it system-wide or application-wide?

Comment: I need it to be system-wide, the idea is to test acceptance of alternate input modes (physical/motion based) for common tasks, and to test if breaking previous methods accelerates and/or prolongs usage

Comment: Windows doesn't know, what a *"primary keyboard"* is supposed to be, neither do I. The same goes for *"main keyboard"*. You'll have to elaborate on what this means in the context of your question.

Comment: I want to prevent selected shortcuts from the HID that represents the keyboard that the user uses to type, etc. I suspect that in the majority of cases it will be the only "keyboard" connected to the machine.
In reality, it would be sufficient to disable to shortcuts on _this_ keyboard, or all keyboards, providing I can still provide those inputs (the shortcuts) programatically.

Comment: *"the HID that represents the keyboard that the user uses to type"* - Vs. the keyboard the user doesn't use to type? That really didn't help much to clarify. I still don't understand what a *"primary"* or *"main"* keyboard is supposed to be, or how to identify it. Not even in the real world. At any rate, if you are running as a service, you are running in session 0. This is not an interactive session, and I would assume that little input travels down there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean? i mean the keyboard that is attached to a personal computer running windows... this can be an external hardware device or built-in as is the case with most laptops.

Comment: The input is gathered from a variety of motion based sensors, this data is processed and emulated inputs are sent to the machine via the input simulator library posted above

Comment: There is a workaround for USB keyboards. USB filter driver could be utilized to stop certain key press event, however, a kernel thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible.  Windows discards the device ID early in keyboard processing; by the time it reaches user mode (a low-level keyboard hook, say) the device ID is gone.   Raw Input lets you track the device-specific input, but doesn't let you block it.

Comment: Thank you, might have to rip apart some keyboards then :/